# __get causes "Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object"

Tags: php, overloading, getter

```
class a
{
}

class b
{
  public function __get($name)
  {
     // Do nothing
  }
}

// Works
$a = new a;
$x = new StdClass();
$a->test =& $x;

// Fatal error:  Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object on line 21
$b = new b;
$y = new StdClass();
$b->test =& $y;
```

How and why does the existence of the magic getter cause this error?

Comment: There is a notice on actual version of PHP: http://3v4l.org/iDKt1